# Pushing to a remote Git server using NetBeans 7.0.1

Tags: git, netbeans, gitosis

I have a Linux server remotely, which has GIT and Gitosis configured. The repository is at git.desytec.com/morros. The URL requires authentication because I don't want it to be viewed by others.

When pushing in NetBeans, I use this URL: git@git.desytec.com:morros/.git but when I click Next, this error occurs:

```
git@git.desytec.com:morros/.git: reject HostKey: git.desytec.com
```

My local machine is running Windows 7.

Comment: Did you tried push once from cli? I think, you have unknown hostkey, which you have to accept once

Comment: @Edwin - pure git:// protocol used, not git+ssh:// - see difference

Answer (score 1):

I got the "does not support smart HTTP push" on all of my git servers. I converted my server to serve git via SSH and a git user, and it still didn't work until I installed the development version of Netbeans 7.2. I used password authentication instead of SSH keys.

Answer (score 0):

If the error message is talking about 'Hostkey', this is an error related to ssh protocol:

```
ssh://git@git.desytec.com:morros/.git
```

If that is the case:

- check your user, user HOME, public and private keys as mentioned in "[Netbeans, git, reject hostKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986617/netbeans-git-reject-hostkey/6992354#6992354)".
- Make sure this isn't related to a [7.0.1 Netbeans bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560186/ssh-problem-using-netbeans-and-git).
- And make sure your [`known_hosts` file is up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448782/how-to-get-netbeans-working-git).

(Also, consider [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), since gitosis is now obsolete, has proven itself problematic in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591958/how-to-change-gitosis-default-search-path))

Comment: I am a bit confused. I will install gitolite, but I got some questions: Gitolite should be installed locally? that is, in my PC with Windows 7? By following  instructions of http://www.philwhln.com/install-gitolite-to-manage-your-git-repositories, adduser command does not work at all                 in my Remote Linux server, for example, neither --system nor --disabled-password options work. Does it matter? Cheers

Comment: @user1048588: Gitolite is installed in the same place, for the same role than gitosis. It is simply more complete in its authorization feature. So you can use on the server the same account than the one used for gitosis. For the installation instructions, I recommend following one of the methods described in http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html or http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/pictures.html#installation_and_setup_. It is more complete than your doc which is one year old.

Comment: the same confusion I have with gitosis.. well.. i have installed gitosis and the same error appears: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.NotSupportedException: remote does not support smart HTTP push.... is there a way to test gitolite installation?

Comment: @user1048588 that doesn't seem to be the same error. Smart HTTP is only supported from Git1.6.6. What version of Git is installed on your server? As well as for testing Gitolite, the real first test is about being able to clone / push back the gitolite amin repo itself (like when you add users or repo to Gitolite, as illustrated by http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/pictures.html#adding_users_to_gitolite_).

Comment: I'm following now this tutorial: http://sites.google.com/site/senawario/home/gitolite-tutorial, but I am stuck in step 3: COPYING YOUR PUBKEY TO THE SERVER. I executed this comman: scp /c/Users/Jaime Stuardo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub "git@git.desytec.com:JAIME.pub" but this error appears: scp: JAIME.pub: No such file or directory

Comment: @user1048588 there is a space in your first path. To be on the safe side, I would put double quotes around it: `scp "/c/Users/Jaime Stuardo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" "git@git.desytec.com:JAIME.pub"`

Comment: VonC, thanks a lot. It appears it is working now.... but, master branch does not appear ina  custom repository. I followed the instructions and git files were created. For example, a file morros.git was created in the remote server, but when I use git@git.desytec.com:morros in Netbeans, no branches appear. On the other hand, if I use git@git.desytec.com:gitolite-admin, master branch appear. Do i need to manually create master branch for morros repository?

Comment: @user1048588: when you are adding a new repo with gitolite, it is an empty one, with no branch at all. It will have a `master` branch once you will push one from your local repo (with the Netbean IDE or with the Git commands). The `gitolite-admin` is a repo already initialized by gitolite, with at least one commit. Hence the branch `master`.