# How to clone repository (using public key) from gitosis server by NetBeans

Tags: git, netbeans, gitosis

I just setup gitosis on my linux machine and everything went fine.

I can clone gitosis-admin, add new user by public key, add new repository, set permission for each user, user can clone repository from gitosis (in linux), also can push change to gitosis server.

Everything went good until I want to develop my project in windows pc by using NetBeans.

I generate RSA key pair by using PuTTY keygen. And send this public key to gitosis user 
then copy this key to `gitosis-admin/keydir`, add new user name for my repo's project in `gigosis-admin/gitosis.conf`, do git add for my new key `git add keydir/myKey.pub` and then push to gitosis server.

Then, I try to clone my repo in NetBeans (using my key). And it show error message like this :

```
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied
```

I can't figured why it happen? I have try to clone my project's repo, using the same key from PuTTY keygen that I just add to gitosis, clone by other local linux machine and it work....

So, Whats wrong? Anyone can help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see various debuging tips for NetBeans and gitosis in "[Pushing to a remote Git server using NetBeans 7.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8145183/6309)".

Specifically, check first the environment variable `HOME` is define in your Windows Session, and known by NetBeans.

You can also check [issue 199263](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199263) for other possible causes.

Comment: How to check $HOME variable in Windows and how to set it? (I'm using window 7)
Thanks

Comment: @NuMeMiie http://superuser.com/a/549450/141 http://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/git-for-windows-tip-setting-home-and-the-startup-directory/ : any ssh command would seek the ssh `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` keys in `%HOME%\.ssh`